# NHibernate transient object exception

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, mapping

I want make an insert in the table EmployeebyProject, when try to insert throw the transient object exception.

Table EmployeebyProject : {**PK: EmployeeId**, **PK: ProjectId**, DateBegin, DateEnd}

This is the mapping:

```
<composite-id>
  <key-many-to-one name="Project" column="ProjectId" class="Project" cascade="save"></key-many-to-one>
  <key-many-to-one name="Employee" column="EmployeeId" class="Employee"></key-many-to-one>
</composite-id>

<property name="DateBegin" type="DateTime"/>
<property name="DateEnd" type="DateTime"/>
```

`enter code here`

How can avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Object from hibernate perspective can be in several states - transient, attached, detached ...
Transient means entity that wasnt saved to the database yet.
If i have relation A->B you need to save B in order to save A (because hibernate need to know what to put in A foreign key to B).

So 2 options:

1. save B before. In your case Project, Employee
2. put cascade . In your case you missing cascade on Employee